# For Loop to Return Unique Values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working through a beginner's ML code, and in order to count the number of unique samples in a column, the author uses this code:

```
def unique_vals(rows, col):
    """Find the unique values for a column in a dataset."""
    return set([row[col] for row in rows])
```

I am working with a DataFrame however, and for me, this code returns single letters: 'm', 'l', etc. I tried altering it to:

```
set(row[row[col] for row in rows)
```

But then it returns:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Grape'   dtype='object', length=2318)] are in the [columns]"
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5):

In general, you don't need to do such things yourself because `pandas` already does them for you.

In this case, what you want is the `unique` method, which you can call on a `Series` directly (the `pd.Series` is the abstraction that represents, among other things, columns), and which returns a `numpy` array containing the unique values in that `Series`.

If you want the unique values for multiple columns, you can do something like this:

```
which_columns = ... # specify the columns whose unique values you want here

uniques = {col: df[col].unique() for col in which_columns}
```

Comment: you can also leverage the fact that Numpy operates on an entire array at once and do `{*np.unique(df[which_columns].values)}`

Comment: @piRSquared I believe that would only work if the columns were homogenous...?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on categorical columns then following code is very useful

**It will not only print the unique values but also print the count of each unique value**

```
col = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'...., 'coln']

#Print frequency of categories
for col in categorical_columns:
    print ('\nFrequency of Categories for varible %s'%col)
    print (bd1[col].value_counts())
```

Example:

```
df

     pets     location     owner
0     cat    San_Diego     Champ
1     dog     New_York       Ron
2     cat     New_York     Brick
3  monkey    San_Diego     Champ
4     dog    San_Diego  Veronica
5     dog     New_York       Ron


categorical_columns = ['pets','owner','location']
#Print frequency of categories
for col in categorical_columns:
    print ('\nFrequency of Categories for varible %s'%col)
    print (df[col].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
# Frequency of Categories for varible pets
# dog       3
# cat       2
# monkey    1
# Name: pets, dtype: int64

# Frequency of Categories for varible owner
# Champ       2
# Ron         2
# Brick       1
# Veronica    1
# Name: owner, dtype: int64

# Frequency of Categories for varible location
# New_York     3
# San_Diego    3
# Name: location, dtype: int64
```